# Sufficient condition for $|1-P(z)|>\left|\frac{(z-a)(1-az)}{b}\right|$ with $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

**Question**

Let $P:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, $a\in(0,1)$ and $b\in\mathbb R_+$. I want to find a   sufficient condition for

$$|1-P(z)|>\left|\frac{(z-a)(1-az)}{b}\right|, \quad \forall \;z\in\mathbb C \quad\text{such that}\; |z|=1,$$

that is not too restrictive.

I understand "not too restrictive" is somewhat subjective, but any improvement on the condition I obtained in my attempt below would be helpful.

---

**My Attempt**

On one hand, it can be shown that
$$|z|=1\;\Rightarrow\;\left|\frac{(z-a)(1-az)}{b}\right|\le \frac{(1+a)^2}{b}.$$
On the other hand, by the reverse triangle inequality
$$|z|=1\;\Rightarrow\;|1-P(z)|\ge|1-|P(z)||,$$
and since for $|z|=1$ we have $|P(z)|\le||P||_2$, then if $||P||_2<1$ we have that
$$|z|=1\;\Rightarrow\;|1-P(z)|\ge 1-||P||_2.$$
Therefore, a sufficient condition is that
$$1-||P||_2>\frac{(1+a)^2}{b}$$
or
$$||P||_2<1-\frac{(1+a)^2}{b}.$$

This condition appears to work, but it seems to me to be unnecessarily restrictive. By looking at the two sides of the inequality separately I have not made use of the fact that $z$ is the same on both sides. I suspect, there may be a way to explore the relationship between the sides.

Comment: What is $\|P\|_2$?

Comment: If $P(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, then $||P||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i^2}$. Thanks, I should have written that down.